# using FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions with asp.net-core6

Tags: fluentvalidation, asp.net-core-6.0

I need to register FluentValidation in core6 Program.cs project file

`services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`

And get an error

> Cannot resolve scoped service 'Application.Validation.FluentValidation.ModelValidators.MyValidator' from root provider.

I have latest FluentValidation and FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions versions

```
<PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="10.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions" Version="10.4.0" />
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to change the [version](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/578) .

Comment: I use latest one
FluentValidation" Version="10.4.0" FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions" Version="10.4.0"

Comment: Can you add more details of the problem? How do you use validators and how MyValidator looks like? Does it accept other services in its constructor? If yes, how they are registred within DI container? Can you share more details of exception i.e. stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error exactly says where's the problem.

Validators are registered as "scoped" and your service provider is not scoped, it's root.

You have to either register validators as no scoped (e.g. singletors) create a scope for your job, which needs them.

E.g.

```
services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```